# Problem with upload file using formData and axios in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I made file upload using formdata and axios in laravel. But there was a problem with retrieving file

Script Code :

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('myfile', self.files);

axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/save',
    data: formData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
}).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

And I retrieving at MyController:

```
public function save(Request $request) {
    $response = array();
    $response['a'] = $request->file('myfile')
    $response['b'] = $request->myfile;
    return Response::json($response);
}
```

Then, check in console :

```
{a: null, b: "[object File]"}
    a: null
    b: "[object File]"
    __proto__: Object
```

I don't know why it is **using dynamic properties** and not **using the file method**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upload files in **Laravel** using **Vue** this way.

**Route (api.php)**

```
Route::post('/upload','mainController@upload');
```

**Controller**

```
public function upload(Request $request){
  $user = User::create($request->only('name'));
   if($request->image) {
        $filename ='_logo_' . str_random(40); 
        //make  directories in public folder as public->uploads->users
        $imagePath = '/uploads/users/' . $filename;
        //use intervention/image package to handle images
        Image::make($request->image)->save(public_path($imagePath));
        $user->image = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success','message' => 'Image was uploaded successfully'],200);
}
```

**Vue.js**
 **template**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
       <form class="needs-validation" novalidate @submit.prevent="uploadImage()">
         <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <input type="file" @change="onFileChange" />
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                   <img class="card-img-top" :src="logo" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
         </div>
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Upload</button>
       </form>
      </div>
</template>
```

**script**

```
export default{
    data(){ 
      return{ 
              logo : null,
              requesting_upload_file:false,

             } 

    },
    methods:{
         onFileChange(e) {
            let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length)
                return;
            this.createImage(files[0]);
        },
        createImage(file) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            let vm = this;
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                vm.logo= e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        uploadImage(){
            let formData = new FormData();
            const config = {
                headers:{'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'}
            };

            if(this.logo){formData.append('logo', this.logo);}

            this.requesting_upload_file = true;
            axios.post('/api/upload',formData,config).then(response => {
               this.requesting_upload_file = false;
               console.log(response)
            }).catch(error => {
                this.requesting_upload_file = false;
                alert(error)
            })
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the part wherein you can use FormData here ?

Comment: in `uploadImage` method

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your headers:

```
        'contentType': false,
        'processData': false
```

Answer (score 0):

The put don't suport, change like trick support post:

```
let frm = = new FormData;
frm.append("_method", "put");
frm.append("key_name", value);
axios.post(url, frm).then(res => { }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
uploadPhoto: function(){
            let that = this;
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', that.photo.file);                 
            axios.post( '/api//save_photo',
            formData,
                {
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
                }
                ).then(function(response){
                    that.errors = response.data.success;
                })
                .catch(function(){
                console.log('FAILURE!!');
                });
            }
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Image;
use File;

protected function saveFilms(Films $request)
    {

        $dir_path = 'uploads/images';
        $dir_path_resize = 'uploads/images/45x45';
        if( $request ){
            $filmsObj = new Film();
            if (!File::exists($dir_path))
            {
                File::makeDirectory($dir_path, 0775, true);
            }
            if (!File::exists($dir_path_resize))
            {
                File::makeDirectory($dir_path_resize, 0775, true);
            }
            if ( $request->file ) {
                $file  = $request->file;
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
                $file_name = 'films_'.\Carbon\Carbon::now().'.'.$extension; 
                $file->move($dir_path, $file_name); 
                $image = Image::make(public_path($dir_path.'/'.$file_name));
                $image->resize(null, 45, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
                $image->save(public_path($dir_path_resize.'/'.$file_name));
        }
            return $return_array;
    }
}
```

Try above code, hope will work.

Comment: I love that you use 'that' instead of _self or something else. Really rolls off the tongue when I say "That Photo File" reading the photo file variable.